# Should I use multiple messenger services in twilio?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I have an app that sends out text confirmations for our companies customers.  We are spread out across the US and using local numbers to contact the customers.  We have some toll free 800 numbers in the pool as backups.

We are about to expand out use of this service and need to purchase over 100 phone numbers.  Of these 100ish numbers there are only about 20 "regions" which could each be their own messenger service theoretically.

Are there any limits on messenger services that would prevent us from loading too many phone numbers?

I'm thinking having 1 messenger service is easier to manage; however I have noticed on occasion a message meant for NY state will be sent from a Texas phone number due to co-pilot balancing the load.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio. I'd love to know a bit more about how you've been using your Messaging Service and your plans with it, so that I can better answer this for you. Can you drop me an email with some more details at philnash@twilio.com? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke to twilio rep in an email and basically I could go either way.  Ended up having 1 messaging service.  Setting up a messaging service for each region seemed like too much maintenance for what it was worth.

He said in the email that there is a soft limit of 100 numbers currently that is supposedly being bumped to 300 in the future.